# how to get the following information to be shown in a spinner or drop down box

Tags: android-studio

I have the following code and I can retrieve the information from firebase but how would I let the user just to select each medical clinic via a drop down box instead? This will then take the user to the next step in writing a review for that particular clinic:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listview;
private EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    listview = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medical Clinic");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);
                assert info != null;
                String txt = info.getName() + " : " + info.getAddress() + " :" + info.getPhone_No() + " : " + info.getPostcode();
                list.add(txt);
               //      list.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using listView, use a spinner

```
Spinner spinner;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_custom_layout, list);
        
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
               // your code
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
        });
```

Update list and notify adapter the same way you have done for the list view adapter with `list.add(txt);` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

spinner_custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/standard_spinner_format"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#000000">

</TextView>
```

The layout file simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml is already in the library and you don't have to create it

Complete java code

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
private EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    listview = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);

    
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_custom_layout, list);
            
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                   // your code
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
            });

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Medical Clinic");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);
                assert info != null;
                String txt = info.getName() + " : " + info.getAddress() + " :" + info.getPhone_No() + " : " + info.getPostcode();
                list.add(txt);
               //      list.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Should I replace the spinner code right before the final arraylist?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_custom_layout,

Comment: I am still confused here but don't we need to add a firebase.getinstance()? I guess this goes in the onItemSelected

Comment: put "this" in place of context if you are in MainActivity

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I am after but I guess, how can I make my firebase items selectable? I like the user to long press the items...

Comment: I thought you had your firebase sorted and just needed to know how to use a dropdown spinner. You dont have any "items" in firestore. These are just fields inside documents which you convert into your desired views in android studio. Once the document is downloaded from firestore, just take the values you need and list them in the spinner.

Comment: I will edit my code because I am trying to follow a tutorial but I have an error about unable to convert to string